# How do I restore Windows XP volume levels?

Tags: windows-xp, audio

Here's a Windows software problem.  I have some software that requires that the volume levels on my audio devices be set *just right*.  In the course of listening to music, using Skype, etc., the volume levels get changed by various other pieces of software.

What software (preferably free/open source) is available that will allow me to set up my audio volume levels just as I need them and then **save** that configuration so that later I can **restore** my volume levels to that saved state with just a few clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Audio Sliders](http://www.codesector.com/audiosliders.php), which should allow you to save and restore volume levels.

From the website:

> Audio Sliders is a Volume Control
>   replacement that is 5 times smaller
>   than the Windows version. The smart,
>   user-friendly interface lets you
>   change volume, bass and treble levels,
>   group playback and recording controls
>   within the five custom layouts and
>   gives the ability to save and restore
>   volume levels.

Comment: This should work fine, and it is free.

Answer (score 0):

[AudioSphere](http://www.svet-soft.com/audio.shtml) is not free, but probably the best match for your requirements.

> features
>
> ```
> *  The fastest access to all controls on one compact faceplate:
> ```
>
> volume, balance, bass, treble and
>   mute. No more hassle with any
>   additional dialogs and confusing
>   controls
>       * One click to normalize all the settings
>       * All functions are accessible via the customizable system wide hotkeys
>       * **Customizable presets**. One for games, second for MP3 listening, third
>   for audio CD, or any other way you
>   wish
>       * Presets buttons on the system tray
>       * Analog clock
>       * Customizable colors, icons and other options to tune the program
>   right up to your need